# Python 3: Trim multibyte string

Tags: string, python-3.x, trim, multibyte

I need to trim a multibyte string so that the remaining characters are still readable in their original encoding (no trailing byte markers).

Example - The following string is 105 characters long. However it is 194 bytes long. When importing this string into a redshift database column with a character limit of 150, I get an overflow error.

```
>>str="Негосударственное образовательное учреждение высшего профессионального образования Институт Уник-70264832"
>>> len(str)
105
>>> len(bytes(str, 'utf-8'))
194
```

How can I safely trim the string down by whole multibyte characters so that I end up with the longest whole character string possible under 150 bytes long?

I know the following works for Python 2, but I need a solution for Python 3.

```
def slice_multibyte(string, length):
    #Loop while string is still longer than required length
    while len(str(string.decode('utf-8'))) > length:
        #Trim off one full utf-8 character (may be multibyte)
        string = string.decode("utf-8")[:len(string.decode("utf-8"))-1].encode("utf-8")
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a bit further, I came up with this solution:

```
def trim_multibyte(string, length):
    while len(bytes(string, 'utf-8')) > length:
        string=string[:-1]
    return string
```

My approach is to shave one character off the end of the string as long as the length of the bytes version of the string is longer than the specified limit.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with certain encodings such as Arabic or Emoticons. I'm open to other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your own solution a bit:

```
import sys

def trim_multibyte(string, length):
    while sys.getsizeof(string) > length:
        string=string[:-1]
    return string

# on a Pandas DataFrame
df.big_column = \
np.where(df.big_column.apply(sys.getsizeof) > 65535,
         df.big_column.apply(trim_multibyte, args=(65535,)), # Redshift VARCHAR limit
         df.big_column)
```